# Complex Matrix is Orthogonal if and only if...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, orthogonal-matrices

Let D be a 2x2 matrix with entries in the complex numbers. Prove that D is orthogonal if and only if, it is of the form:

\begin{pmatrix}
a & -b\\ 
b & a
\end{pmatrix}
or
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\ 
b & -a
\end{pmatrix}

Proof. I've already proved that if D is equal to those forms then, it implies that D is an orthogonal matrix. But how can I prove this? If D is orthogonal, then it must be of the form:
\begin{pmatrix}
a & -b\\ 
b & a
\end{pmatrix}
or
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\ 
b & -a
\end{pmatrix}

**Update:** a and b must satisfy that $a^2+b^2=1$

Comment: This is false. Consider $\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}$ for instance.

Comment: @user1551 I don't think that matrix is orthogonal, is it?

Comment: @inavda Why not? It has two orthonormal columns.

Comment: Oops, my bad - I misread it.

Comment: Sorry! Please see the updated question. My fault.

Comment: The modified statement is still false. Consider $\pmatrix{0&2\\ 2&0}$ for instance. It is of the form $\pmatrix{a&b\\ b&-a}$ but it is not orthogonal.

Comment: @user1551 I think one needs to add the condition $a^2+b^2=1$, no?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, again not including that was my fault

Comment: Start with the necessary condition that column vectors need to be (pairwise) orthonormal.

Comment: I just want to note that orthogonal matrices with complex entries are a slightly odd thing to consider. The natural generalization of orthogonal matrices to complex numbers are unitary matrices, which fulfill $\overline{A}^TA=I$ instead of $A^TA=I$.

Comment: If the matrices are complex, why orthogonal instead of unitary?

Answer (score 1):

Let a 2x2 matrix $A$ be orthogonal i.e $AA^t = A^tA = E$. Notice that
$$ E= \left (\begin{array}{cc}a & b \\ c & d\end{array} \right )\left (\begin{array}{cc}a & c \\ b & d\end{array} \right ) \Rightarrow \|(a,b)\| = \|(c,d)\| = 1,\ (a,b)\perp (c,d) $$
Conversely, suppose a 2x2 matrix $A$ has orthonormal columns $(a,b)^t$ and $(c,d)^t$. Then
$$ A^tA = \left (\begin{array}{cc}a & b \\ c & d\end{array} \right )\left (\begin{array}{cc}a & c \\ b & d\end{array} \right ) = \left ( \begin{array}{cc}a^2 + b^2 & 0 \\ 0 & c^2+d^2 \end{array} \right ) = E $$
Likewise $AA^t = E$.

---

For the complex case we say a square matrix $A$ is unitary, if $A^HA=AA^H = E$, where $A^H := \overline{A}^t$. Orthonormality of column vectors remains an equivalent condition.

Answer (score 1):

If $A= \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ 
c & d\end{pmatrix}$
then we get from $A^TA= I$ that $a^2+c^2=1= b^2+d^2$ and also $ab+cd = 0$. Then $ab = -cd$ so squaring it gives $a^2b^2 = c^2d^2$. I'll let you finish the rest.

Answer (score 0):

**To Prove:** If A is a 2x2 orthogonal matrix, A is of the form given in the question.

**Proof:**
For any general non-singular matrix, $A= \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ 
c & d\end{pmatrix}$,
$\begin{equation}\det(A) = ad-bc \end{equation}$ and
$A^T= \begin{pmatrix}a & c \\ 
b & d\end{pmatrix}$.

Using $ \begin{align}A A^T = I \end{align} $, we get $\begin{equation}a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + d^2 = 1\end{equation}$ and $\begin{equation}ac=-bd\end{equation}$.

Using $\begin{align} A^T = A^{-1} \end{align}$, we get $\begin{equation}ad-bc = \frac{d}{a} = \frac{a}{d} = \frac{c}{-b} = \frac{-b}{c}\end{equation}$.

On solving $\begin{equation}d^2 = a^2 \end{equation}$  and $\begin{equation} b^2 = c^2 \end{equation}$ (obtained from above equation) and satisfying in $\begin{equation}ac=-bd\end{equation}$.
You get the required matrices.